# strapi error while using data transfer command

Tags: postgresql, content-management-system, strapi, remix

while running this command to transfer strapi local instance data to remote instance
***npm run strapi transfer -- --to https://div-strapi.azurewebsites.net/admin***

i am getting a error: too many arguments for 'transfer'. Expected 0 arguments but got 1.
the data is in postgresSql db
how to fix it. this is the exact same command that is provided in strapi docs

how to fix it ? any alternate command, i am using windows machine and npm

Comment: Have you tried using yarn instead, just to see if that works.  I tried on the mac using yarn and it worked.  yarn strapi transfer --to destinationURL

Answer (score 0):

Yarn works without any issues, here is the command.

```
  yarn strapi transfer --to destinationURL
```

There is a bug when using npm

instead of

```
run strapi transfer -- --to https://div-strapi.azurewebsites.net/admin
```

and try

```
run strapi transfer -- -- --to https://div-strapi.azurewebsites.net/admin
```

But if possible try using yarn.

Let me know if that works?

Comment: I will create a bug report when get a chance.